# Partition function of an ideal gas (taking gravity into account)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, partition-function

I am trying to solve the following problem from an old qualifying exam:

*"Ideal gas in gravitational potential"*

*Consider an ideal gas of N indistinguishable molecules of mass m in a cylindrical volume $V=Ah$ with base area A and height h.*

*Calculate the canonical partition function of the ideal gas including the effect of gravity. (Hint: You may find useful the integral $\int_0^\infty  t^2 e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi/4}$).*

My work so far:

Since the partition function of a total system is the product of the partition function of the subsystems, i.e. if there are N subsystems, we'd have

$$
Z_{total} = Z_1 Z_2 Z_3 ... Z_N = \prod_i^N Z_i
$$

Moreover, if (as is the case in this instance) the subsystems are indistinguishable, we can (after correct Boltzmann counting) reduce this to,

$$
Z_{total} = \frac{1}{N!} (Z_1)^N
$$

where $Z_1$ is the partition function of 1 molecule of an ideal gas subject to gravity.

**Question #1:**

The solution accompanying this problem makes the following adjustment to my above expression for $Z_{total}$. Notably, they use Stirling's formula to write out N!. However, I'm either making a silly mistake, or the solution is wrong.

Using Stirling's formula

$$
N! \propto (\frac{N}{e})^N
$$

I would think that

$$
Z_{total} = \frac{1}{N!} (Z_1)^N = \bigg(\frac{Z_1 e}{N}\bigg)^N
$$

but the solution says

$$
Z_{total} = \bigg(\frac{Z_1 N}{e}\bigg)^N
$$

**Question #2:**

$Z_1$, the partition function for one of the gas molecules subject to gravity is

$$
Z_1 = \frac{1}{h^3} \int d^3p d^3q e^{-\beta H}
$$

where $h$ is Plank's constant, $\beta = 1/T$, and $H$ is the Hamiltionian for a single molecule accounting for both the particles momentum and gravity ($H=\frac{p^2}{2m} + mgy$, with y being the height of the particle).

The first step that the solution takes in evaluating this integral is the following

$$
\begin{align}
Z_1 &= \frac{1}{h^3} \int d^3p d^3q e^{-\beta H} \\
 &= \frac{1}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \int  e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}} d^3p \int  e^{-\beta m g y} d^3q\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \int  e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}} d^3p \cdot A \int_0^h  e^{-\beta m g y}dy
\end{align}
$$

where recall that A is the area of the cylinder and h in the height.

Now the next step is where I'm thoroughly confused,

$$
\begin{align}
Z_1 &=\frac{1}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \int  e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}} d^3p \cdot A \int_0^h  e^{-\beta m g y} dy \\
&=\frac{4 \pi}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \int_0^\infty  p^2 e^{-\beta \frac{p^2}{2m}} dp \cdot A \int_0^h  e^{-\beta m g y} dy
\end{align}
$$

My only guess is switching to polar and changing the limits of integration?

Can someone clarify these two questions for me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1) I think, that this is typo in answers..

2) $d^3 p = 4\pi p^2 dp$ if we are consider quantity under integration, that depend only on on modulus of $p$.

To understand this imagine spherical coordinates in 3d:
$$
dxdydz = r^2 sin\theta \;dr d\theta d\phi
$$

And after integration over sphere you obtain $4\pi$.